# Editor's Auto-completer dosen't come up when we type "-"

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, ace-editor

The ace editors auto-completer doesn't show up after using "-" (Dash or minus operator). But the completer shows suggestions for other common operators like  + , - , * . /

I have tried the ctrl+space option too for pulling up the pane, but it did not help me either.
[image]

Comment: Did you ever found a solution?

Comment: No, Not yet @d.h.

Comment: Have you been facing the same Issue? @d.h.

Comment: Kind of... The ace editor recognizes the "-" as part of the autocompletion strings. We have words that are combined like "WORD-WORD" and the editor shows only those entries. If we type a "+" it always shows the complete list. If no entries with "-" are present then the autocompletions doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah, can we enhance the library file for this case to support "-" normally as "+"? Or Can we raise an Issue with Ace's Github Source on this?

Comment: We found the following regex inside ext-language-tools.js: "var ID_REGEX = /[a-zA-Z_0-9\$\-\u00A2-\uFFFF]/;" If you remove the "\-" after the $-sign the minus is working again. I suppose they had it in the first place because a minus is a valid character in a string (for example a name like Ann-Marie).

Comment: Yes, this is working. Need to check if this change in Library file is good though. Need it officially done from them right?

Comment: This regex is the default behaviour, you can override it with your own. From what I can see the getCompletionPrefix() function uses completer.identifierRegexps if its supplied.

Comment: I changed my answer..seems that in the official branch of the ace editor its not possible to change that regex from outside..But there is the fork I mentioned.

Comment: If you don't want to modify the core files I would say it is not possible to achieve what you want right now. Hope my answers still helped a bit...

Answer (score 2):

You can override the default behaviour

`var ID_REGEX = /[a-zA-Z_0-9\$\-\u00A2-\uFFFF]/;`

which is defined in ext-language_tools.js (in older versions) or in autocomplete/utils.js.

From the following code you can see that each completer can have its own regex supplied by identifierRegexps (string):

```
exports.getCompletionPrefix = function (editor) {
    var pos = editor.getCursorPosition();
    var line = editor.session.getLine(pos.row);
    var prefix;
    editor.completers.forEach(function(completer) {
        if (completer.identifierRegexps) {
            completer.identifierRegexps.forEach(function(identifierRegex) {
                if (!prefix && identifierRegex)
                    prefix = this.retrievePrecedingIdentifier(line, pos.column, identifierRegex);
            }.bind(this));
        }
    }.bind(this));
    return prefix || this.retrievePrecedingIdentifier(line, pos.column);
};
```

From my tests I can say that this does not work properly because if the prefix is empty the default regex will be used:

```
return prefix || this.retrievePrecedingIdentifier(line, pos.column);
```

Furthermore I found a pull request on the github page with the same issue:
https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/pull/2905

I also created an issue on the ace editor's github page:
https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/3430

**UPDATE (03.04.2018):**

It seems that this feature finally made its way into the project:

https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/pull/2905#pullrequestreview-108526630

Answer (score 1):

`Ace.Completer` interface has `identifierRegexps` key,
to exclude minus("-") sign:

```
const completer: Ace.Completer = {
  identifierRegexps: [/[a-zA-Z_0-9\$\u00A2-\uFFFF]/],
}

editor.completers = [completer];
```